# Cannot pass Array elements to restore a form

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

I am beginner in JavaScript. For exercise, I try to restore a form (at page closed / page reloaded) using cookies. I take the following steps:

- Create an array with form selections
- Convert to string
- Create cookie
- Retrieve cookie
- Extract string
- Convert to array

... Until here everything goes perfect. But the next step doesn't work anymore...

- Pass array values to restore the form elements

Regardless the form selections (present correctly in the retrieved array) after reloading page I get every time only last the radio button checked (even if I increase or reduce the number of buttons) and all checkboxes checked.

I tried anything I know to find the error but no success. I also converted the string "true"/"false" values to Boolean, but no change.

The real situation:

```
frm[0]=true
frm[1]=false // for two radio buttons
frm[2]=false
frm[3]=false // for two checkboxes
document.getElementById("myradio1").checked=frm[0]
document.getElementById("myradio2").checked=frm[1]
document.getElementById("mycheckbox1").checked=frm[2]
document.getElementById("mycheckbox2").checked=frm[3] // pass the array values to the form elements
```

But, as I said, any values I pass I always get selected the last radio buttons and all checkboxes.

Probably this code doesn't follow the "best practices" of JavaScript, but before I change it I want to understand why it behaves like this. I thank you in advance for your comments, because I want very much to clarify this issue.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because for a radio button, only one radio button can be clicked in a group of radio buttons.

And for the checkboxes, you are using the same ID twice, so the change isn't actually reflecting on the other checkboxes.

Comment: 1. Yes, I know that radio buttons function like you said. Still, I don't see the connection of your comment with my issue. This is what I want (and what is normal): only one radio button to be selected. But what I say is that ANY button I select, after page reload ALWAYS is selected the last one in the group. Ignoring the array data. 2. Sorry, was a typo. I corrected it now. My question remains valid.